# Why should I use metadata when putting objects in AWS S3?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In [AWS SDK for PHP v3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html) the method [putObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject) can receive many parameters like `ContentType`, `ContentEncoding`, etc.

[In it's simplest form](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpPHP.html), I can put a object using only `Bucket`, `Key` and `SourceFile`:

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'       => $bucket,
    'Key'          => $keyname,
    'SourceFile'   => $filepath
));
```

Considering that my app is going to insert photos and they must stay in S3 until I order to delete it, what are the pros and cons of setting metadata on them, like `ContentType`, `ContentEncoding` and others?

Will it's simplest form passing only `Bucket`, `Key` and `SourceFile` attend my goals?

Comment: You will thank yourself eventually if you set `ContentType` correctly **now**.  It's not much fun to go back and fix it later.  The others also have correct values, though "correct" sometimes means the value should not be set (this is often true with `ContentEncoding`).  Whether it will "attend your goals" is a matter of what your goals are.  You need to make the effort to learn what each of these means, and set the values appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will it's simplest form passing only Bucket, Key and SourceFile attend my goals?

The answer is **Yes** it will serve your purpose but if you use Metadata then you can have more control over your object.

According to AWS documentation about Object Metadata,

There are two kinds of Meta data:

- **System metadata** : Metadata such as object creation Date, Last-Modified, Content-Length are system controlled where only Amazon S3 can modify the value.
- **User-defined metadata** : You can set/modify optional information as a name-value (key-value) pair when you send a PUT or POST request to create the object and you can grab them in future also.

Use Case:

> If you have your bucket configured as a website, sometimes you might
>   want to redirect a page request to another page or an external URL. In
>   this case, a web page is an object in your bucket. Amazon S3 stores
>   the page redirect value as system metadata whose value you control.
>    When you create objects, you can configure values of these system
>   metadata items or update the values

For more info about Object Meta Data,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata

Comment: Also you could have finer cache control if you are using S3 as origin for a CDN (Content Deliver Network). 
You can set `s-maxage` for example and your CDN would pick it up.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationAddingHeadersInS3

Comment: **There are in fact 3 kinds of metadata** because system metadata is divided into two distinct categories -- the one you described and the other, which is user-specified but system-constrained, like `x-amz-storage-class`.  The mention of *sometimes you might want to redirect a page request to another page or an external URL* seems like a distraction, largely irrelevant in the context of the question, and used much more rarely than almost any other example of metadata.  It also seems out of place at its location, here, since it's actually an example of system metadata, not user metadata.

Answer (score 4):

You have system metadata and user metadata.

You can just stick to using bucket and key name only.
However depending on your application logic user-metadata comes in handy in various cases.
For example you can add extra information such as the username of the person that uploaded the original version of the file.

However be aware of the limitations and don't overdo it.

> The PUT request header is limited to 8 KB in size. Within the PUT request header, the user-defined metadata is limited to 2 KB in size. The size of user-defined metadata is measured by taking the sum of the number of bytes in the UTF-8 encoding of each key and value.